# How Can I Create a Keyframeable Animation of Changing Numbers?

Tags: animation

So ... I have several different video clips I'm editing together. Some are of a SCUBA diver during his dive, others are of a cyclist touring the countryside. I need to overlay on these videos a keyframe-able animation of numbers to track data during these events.

For the SCUBA diver, I need to be able to overlay the diver's depth and the water's temperature as it changes over the course of time during the dive. For the cyclist, I need to be able to overlay the cyclist's speed and overall mileage over time during the ride.

It's been almost two decades since I've cracked a 3D Modeling program, and that was Maya when it was produced by Alias. So, I'm not that well versed with Blender. That being said, I do have some mild knowledge, so I hope to be able to follow along any tips.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found a video on how to change a text object to act like a countdown timer. I imagine if you keyframed the numbers going up or down with certain values. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nf79mn71SYA

Comment: there's an addon called Text Effects, maybe it does what you want? https://blendermarket.com/products/ik-text-effects/